# How to override a gem controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Rails 5.1 and the TrestleAdmin Gem.

I'd like to override the flash notification in the controller and did copy the file `gems/trestle-0.8.2/lib/trestle/resource/controller.rb` into `my_app/lib/trestle/resource/` folder and made a few changes in the controller file.

But this doesn't affect anything.

What's the proper way to monkey-patch the controller?

Comment: Please see e.g. [this page](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/)

Comment: Did you add `super` to the method  and then write codes below?
This article might help you.
http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_overriding_methods.html